# SQL how to replace string which contains only new lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My situation is that in some cases my field contain several (multiple) new lines and nothing else.

I can't use this:

```
  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(fielddata, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

because I also have a normal ones, and as I understand this will replace all new lines.

As I understand, I need somehow check if string contains only new lines, and if it does, replace them with ''.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Is this for a select statement, an update statement? some wider context would help you to get a better answer.

Comment: I updated question. It is a select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is to use case, len, and trim to figure out if the column have data in that specific row:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(
                     LTRIM(
                           RTRIM(
                             REPLACE(
                                     REPLACE(
                                             fielddata, CHAR(13), ''
                                             ), CHAR(10), ''
                                    )
                                )
                          )
                    ) = 0 THEN
           ''
       ELSE
           fielddata
       END as fielddata
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression like

```
CASE WHEN REPLACE(my_string_column, CHAR(13), '')  = ''
THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(fielddata, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
ELSE my_string_column END AS Computed_Column
```

Comment: `my_string_column = CHAR(13)` != `only new lines`

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this will not work if string has multiple new lines

Comment: @IvanStarostin, yes true but what about now?

Comment: Thanks for answering , unfortunately no, not working. I guess when lack of char(10)